# Best way to calculate the square root of any number in ios , Objective C and Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, square-root

I am asking for ways to calculate the square root of any given number in `ios`,  `Objective C`. I have inserted my way to do it using log. the logic was. ex : find the square root of 5

```
X = √5
```

then

```
log10X = log10(√5)
```

this means

```
log10X = log10(5)/2;
```

then should get the value of `log10(5)` and `divide` it from `2` and after that shoud get the `antilog` of that value to search `X`.

**so my answer is in Objective C is like below (as an ex: I'm searching the square root of 5)**

```
double getlogvalue = log10(5)/2; // in here the get the value of 5 in log10 and divide it from two.

//then get the antilog value for the getlogvalue

double getangilogvalue = pow(10,getlogvalue);

//this will give the square root of any number. and the answer may include for few decimal points. so to print with two decimal point,

NSLog(@"square root of the given number  is : %.02f", getantilogvalue);
```

**If anyone have any other way/answers. to get the square root of any given value , add please add and also suggestions for above answer is also accepted.**

**This is open for swift developers too. please add there answers also, becasue this will help to anyone who want to calculate the square root of any given number.**

Comment: Also note that both (Objective-)C and Swift have a `sqrt()` function in the standard library: `double sqrtFive = sqrt(5.0);`

Comment: yep, this is a question. accept your comment @MartinR

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `sqrt` function (and other mathematical functions as well) is
available in the standard libraries on all OS X and iOS platforms.

It can be used from (Objective-)C:

```
#include "math.h"

double sqrtFive = sqrt(5.0);
```

and from Swift:

```
import Darwin // or Foundation, Cocoa, UIKit, ...

let sqrtFive = sqrt(5.0)
```

Comment: just to know , do we have to `import` `"math.h"`, or can't we use it defaultly without import .

Comment: @AnuradhS: You have to include "math.h" (or any other header which includes "math.h"). Otherwise the function is assumed to return an `int` – and Xcode should warn you about "implicitly declaring a function".

Comment: In pure Swift 3+: `import Swift; let sqrtFive = 5.0.squareRoot()`

Comment: @Cœur: Yes, that is what Paul said (it was not available at the time when I wrote this answer).

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3,

```
 x = 4.0
 y = x.squareRoot()
```

since the `FloatingPoint` protocol has a squareRoot method and both `Float` and `Double` comply with the FloatingPoint protocol. This should be higher performance than the sqrt() function from either Darwin or Glibc, since the code it generates will be from the LLVM built-in square root, so no function call overhead on systems with hardware square root machine code.

Comment: As far as I can see, the generated assembly code is the same for `sqrt(x)` and `x.squareRoot()`, at least on the macosx platform.