# How to calculate SquareRoot of Integer without using inbuilt function in Swift Language? I tried below code & searched but didn't get better solution

Tags: swift, data-structures, square-root

Just an exercise:

```
func mySqrt(_ x: Int) -> Int {
    if x<2 { return x }
    
    var y = x
    var z = (y + (x/y)) / 2

    while Double(abs(y - z)) >= 0.00001 {
      y = z
      z = (y + (x/y)) / 2
    }
    
    return z
  }
```

I went through many answers in StackOverflow but couldn't get a better solution, e.g.

[Best way to calculate the square root of any number in ios , Objective C and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190082/best-way-to-calculate-the-square-root-of-any-number-in-ios-objective-c-and-swi/40953774#40953774)

[Finding square root without using sqrt function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611198/finding-square-root-without-using-sqrt-function)

Take input x = 4 or any perfect square, it works fine. Now, take something like x = 8, It Time out.

Please help me out, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why should a sqrt function return an integer, what is the expected result for `mySqrt(8)` for instance?

Comment: Note that square root is an expensive operation. The built-in function takes advantage of hardware acceleration, and is likely **thousands** of times faster than doing it manually. I'm assuming this is an exercise?

Comment: @DuncanC Yes this is just exercise

Comment: It would be interesting to benchmark the manual vs. built-in version. I bet you could calculate >1000 square roots with the built-in faster than you could calculate a single non-perfect-square value.

Comment: @DuncanC True that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to use integers for all of the calculations.

The square root of 8 is not an integer. You need to use `Double` for all of your variables (except optionally leave parameter as an `Int`). The return value needs to be a `Double` if you want a meaningful answer.

Here's your code using `Double` where needed:

```
func mySqrt(_ x: Int) -> Double {
    if x < 2 { return Double(x) }

    var y = Double(x)
    var z = (y + (Double(x)/y)) / 2

    while (abs(y - z)) >= 0.00001 {
        y = z
        z = (y + (Double(x)/y)) / 2
    }

    return z
}

print(mySqrt(8))
```

This gives the correct result.